# blank <img src> custom directive in Angular JS and I was referring to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_okHflzgm0

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs and I was trying to create custom directive and for that I was following steps from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_okHflzgm0  I did exactly what was shown here but for some reason img src is blank I dont know what is wrong in my code

//created new app

```
var myApp=angular.module('myFirstApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

//configured routing

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

      $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/directory', {
          templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
          controller: 'NinjaController'
        }).otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

//custom directive

```
myApp.directive('randomNinja', [function(){

  return{


    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      ninjas: '=',
      title: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/random.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    }

  };
}]);
```

//controller

```
myApp.controller('NinjaController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){

  $http.get('data/ninjas.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.ninjas=response.data;
  }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })

  $scope.removeNinja=function(ninja){
    var ninjaRemoved=$scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
    $scope.ninjas.splice(ninjaRemoved, 1)
  }
  $scope.addNinja=function(){
    $scope.ninjas.push({
      name: $scope.newNinja.name,
      belt: $scope.newNinja.belt,
      rate: parseInt($scope.newNinja.rate),
      available:true
    })
    $scope.newNinja.name='',
    $scope.newNinja.belt='',
    $scope.newNinja.rate=''

  }
```

//image links

[Inspect view from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7KGV.png)

[JSON data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt98c.png)

[Home with custom directive and random view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iIYn.png)

Comment: Need to see your `views/random.html` file. It looks like you have multiple problems. `ninjas[random].thumb` looks wrong to me

Comment: Hi thanks for your interest I have attached image of my random.html and json data in this post also for home.html file please check attached images once

Comment: I have my files on git hub also let me know if github link is required

Comment: sorry my bad I forgot to add controller in routeProvider for /home so home.html didn't have any access to controller data

Comment: How do I close this question I am not able to accept my own answer because I only have 1 point

Comment: I will nominate it to be closed - glad you got it fixed